Does Trump support removing vaccine liability shields?
Former President Trump’s Transition Team co-chair Howard Lutnick just said this to CNN’s Kaitlan Collins, about what Robert F. Kennedy Jr’s role will be in a Trump administration:

He’s not getting a job for HHS.  Here’s what he’s trying to do.  What he wants to do, he said he “I want data. I just want data because they block the data.” […] He wants the data so he can say “These things are unsafe.”  He says “If you give me the data, all I want is the data, and I’ll take on the data and show that it’s not safe.” And then when you pull the product liability, the companies will yank these vaccines right off of the market.

I’m interested in the part in bold.  The National Childhood Vaccine Injury Act, signed into law by Ronald Reagan in 1986, limits the financial liability borne by vaccine manufacturers for vaccine injuries, injury claims being settled through no-fault arbitration instead, on the grounds that it would be unprofitable to manufacture vaccines otherwise due to nuisance litigation costs.
My question is, has Trump expressed support for getting rid of this liability shield?  Or is Lutnick just describing his own personal view and/or that of Kennedy?

It depends whether pharma donated enough to his campaign, I guess. Right now they're just saying something ambiguous enough to attract RFK voters. E.g. RFK was invited to speak at a Trump rally last week https://www.rollingstone.com/politics/politics-news/trump-transition-boss-praises-rfk-jr-vaccine-conspiracies-1235148494/ And it's not Trump whose saying that. Just another guy who Trump might fire a year down the road.

FWTW RFK said "President Trump has promised me is control of the public health agencies, which are HHS and its sub-agencies, CDC, FDA, NIH, and a few others … and then also the USDA". I really doubt Trump will keep that promise, if he's ever actually made it, since RFK is also a liar sometimes. N.B. Trump's campaign then denied they made that promise, although not through Lutnick who was far more ambiguous. So, my guess is that Lutnick supports RFK (for a job like that) but others in Trump's entourage do not. So,  "we'll see".

It's also interesting to read the transcript of the leaked conversation between Trump and RFK. Trump says things that almost sound like a promise, but are really not, like "Trump added that he would “love” for Kennedy to “serve.”
“I think it would be so good for you and so big for you,” he said. “And we’re gonna win.”".
